# Can download_fileobj() append to rather than overwrite the destination file?

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

In the following code, let `object` and `object2` be instances of boto3's "s3.Object" type:

```
data = open('out.dat', 'wb')

object.download_fileobj(data)
object2.download_fileobj(data)
```

The result is that 'out.dat' will contain the contents of object2 - not the concatenation of object and object2 as I expected.  Is there a way to get download_fileobj() to append to the download destination rather than overwrite it?

The reason I would expect the concatenated result is by analogy with this:

```
with open('test.file', 'wb') as data:
  data.write('hello')
  data.write(' world')
```

The file contents are the concatentation of the "write()" calls.

To make things even more confusing, the following yields the concatenation of the S3 objects:

```
with open('out.dat', 'ab') as data:
  object.download_fileobj(data)
  object2.download_fileobj(data)
```

Changing the file mode from 'wb' to 'ab' results in concatentation behavior rather than overwrite behavior.  But I would have thought that 'ab' vs. 'wb' would have no difference after the file open operation - which happens just once - and therefore no effect on the result (assuming 'out.dat' does not exist initially.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that is not what `ab` mode is for?

```
data = open('out.dat', 'wb')

object.download_fileobj(data)
data.close();

data = open('out.dat','ab'); 
object2.download_fileobj(data)
data.close();
```

Now `data` will both objects.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT1:**

This is better only if you run it once,

```
with open('out.dat', 'ab') as data:
  object.download_fileobj(data)
  object2.download_fileobj(data)
```

ab -- opens in append binary mode. One dangerous thing is the code is not rerunnable.

If you run it again, it will looks like this, object + object2 + object + object2. Fil opens in append mode and whatever it is written goes to the end of the file.

Comment: Indeed this works, though I have to admit I am confused about how it does - I'll add more explanation in the question